# How do I find the largest numbers in a area, and then find the value of a number in the same row?

Tags: excel

I cannot find a way to do this, is it possible (with excel functions or VBS)?

For example, these would be the initial values:

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 234 |
| 102 | 324 |
| 103 | 345 |
| 104 | 325 |
| 105 | 437 |
| 106 | 443 |
| 107 | 806 |
| 108 | 476 |
| 109 | 538 |
| 110 | 546 |

And after taking the three highest numbers, this would be the output:

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 107 | 806 |
| 110 | 546 |
| 109 | 538 |

The data is constantly updating, so that might cause some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FILTER` in combination with `LARGE` function to achieve this:

Columns A and B represent sample data. Cell D2 can contain this formula:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9>=LARGE($B$2:$B$9,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If data is constantly updating, better to have an Excel Table (I named `TB_NumVal`), so the range index get automatically updated.

In cell: `J2`:

```
=SORT(FILTER(SORT(TB_NumVal,2), (ROW(TB_NumVal[Number])-1) 
  > ROWS(TB_NumVal[Number])-3),2,-1)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

We sort the data, then since we start on row 2 (row 1 is the header) we substract `1`. So

```
ROW(TB_NumVal[Number])-1
```

will provide the row number starting from one.

```
ROWS(TB_NumVal[Number])
```

is the total number of rows, in our case `10`.

Using a filter condition like this:

```
(ROW(TB_NumVal[Number])-1) > ROWS(TB_NumVal[Number])-3)
```

ensures only the last three row will be selected, then finally sorted the filtered result by value in descending order to match the result of the screenshot of the question.